# i need only one address from forEach but i get multiple in JSTL Submit button with in forEatch?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

I am trying to create multiple submit buttons generated by JSTL forEach loop, but I am getting a list of values in my controller.

I am using JSP with Spring MVC. Below is the code of my .jsp page,

```
`<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="text" name="lname">
<c:forEach items="${modList}" var="mod">
     <input type="hidden" name="address" value="mod.address">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="address">
</c:forEach>`
```

I am getting a list of all values but I want only one the one for the button submitted. Could anyone help?

Comment: If I understood correctly, yout problem is with the HTML generated (can you update and provide this code?), you have one form with multiples submit and input with same address name, because you have more than one item in modList...In the submit, they will be overwritted by last provided value.

Answer (score 0):

Your forEach loop is iterating over the number of items in modList and generating submit buttons.

So it depends what values you have in modList. If you want to get the "submitted" address then you may want to do an if in the loop to check if it is the correct/submitted mod. What values are in modList?

You are just creating a submit button for each item in modList.